# UITableViewController accessing static cells programmatically issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Say I have a table with 10 static cells in it, is there a way to select a certain cell programmatically?

I've tried this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView.subviews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

but that does not actually return a table cell it seems.

this seems to crash my code

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Im trying to set the individual heights for the static cells in code. An option would be to make outlets for each individual static cell, but that seems silly.

Comment: What do you mean by "static cell"? For a bit more general answer: Why do you want to access the cell directly? And where in your code do you access it?

Comment: UITabelViews can either have prototype cells that are generated in code and partly in the story board (optionally), or static cells that are made in the storyboard editor completely(normally) and the number of cells dont vary

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To access statically created cells, try this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This works for static cells. So, if you're in the...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;

}
```

... delegate, you can access all statically configured cells using the above declaration. From there, you can do what ever you want with "cell".

I had a ViewController that had two UITableViews on it. One of them had cells defined statically, with a Storyboard, and the other had cells defined dynamically using code. Given I was using the same ViewController as delegate for both tables, I needed to prevent new cells from being created where cellForRowAtIndexPath was being called where cells had already been created.

In your case, you need to gain programmatic access to your cells.

Have fun.

Comment: Hi, I searched all over stack overflow ad found your solution. However, I'm working with Xamarin.iOS whose implementation is in c#. Do you have any pointers how to get this working for Monotouch?

Answer (score 9):

Create an `@IBOutlet`.

This will work even if you re-arrange your static cells programmatically.

Comment: Been looking for a while! This is the best solution to a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowvalue inSection:0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need accessing the cell object, then using UITableViewCell method cellForRowAtIndexPath is quite appropriate.

That may either just pass the cell, if it is visible, or call the delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath (do not mix them up) which you should provide. If that one crashes then dig deeper and investigate the root cause of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Use `table view delegate` method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSInteger height;  
     if(0 == indexPath.row)  
       {
          height = 44;
       }
     else
      {  
        height = 50;
      }
   return height;
}
```

Comment: ok fair enough, that does answer my question, but what if I was trying to do something else to the cell as well. Is there not a way to get a reference to the actual cell object?

Comment: As Anil suggests, you have to use the delegate messages to update your cells. If you want to reload cell at index 3, you should call the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: message passing that row, and then your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: message will be called.

Comment: [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath] will give your cell object

Comment: @anil i have tried that but it seems to make my program crash, maybe the way Ricard suggested will work though

Answer (score 0):

This is a Swift 2.3. Solution.

The UITableViewController is created in IB.

```
/*
    NOTE
    The custom static cells must be
    In the IB tableview if one is being used 
    They also must be updated to be MYCustomTableViewCell 
    instead of UITableViewCell
*/
import UIKit

class MYCustomTableVC: UITableViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // NO Nib registration is needed
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! MYCustomTableViewCell
        // MYCustomTableViewCell can be created programmatically 
        // without a Xib file 
        return cell
    }
}
```