# Static UITableViewCell backgroundColor always white on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

In my project, I have a static TableView. I changed the backgroundColor of the cells in interface builder. This shows correctly on iPhone.

However, on iPad the cells background is always white.

I found a solution for dynamic cells [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30903407/4147323), but as it is using the UITableViewDataSource protocol, i can't use it with my static table.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: try to set cell.contentView.backgroundColor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the `cell.contentView.backgroundColor`, as @SandeepAggarwal has pointed out.

Comment: That was the obvious part to me. However you answered my question correctly, so I will accept the answer. My real problem was, how to access the static UITableViewCells. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15277305/4147323) pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

try this , it will solve your problem