# Add a new TableView inside a subview of another tableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableViewController` that contains static table view cell.
In the last cell, I added a `UIScrollView` and I added a subview inside it.

In this subview, I added another `tableView` with dynamic cell.

The problem is, I have used tableview protocols for the main `tableViewController` cells (the static one), I don't know how I can use them again for dynamic table view in the subview. 
Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Hierarchy of views you have created is not ideal, but, to answer the question; set the delegates of the tableView to the last tableViewCell in which you have added it as subview. 
Hence, your main tableView's delegate will be called inside controller and, the delegate for tableView inside last cell will be called inside cell itself.

Comment: thank you so much for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

- Check for which `UITableView` are protocols' method called by checking for which table view is method's `tableView` parameter equal

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      switch tableView {
      case someTableView1: // ...
      case someTableView2: // ...
      default: return
      }
  }
  ```
- Create subclass of `UITableViewCell` for your static cells/cell and implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols to this subclass

Comment: Thanks dear @Robert, I think I go with the first way, just a question, I should define tableviews as outlets and then use them in switch cases, is it right?

Comment: Dear @Robert, I have a problem here. in cellForRowAt, If i use switch case, how can define cell of static cells?

Comment: @JOnney https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726943/uitableviewcontroller-accessing-static-cells-programatically-issue/15277305?